# jqGrid - make all columns not sortable?

Tags: jquery, configuration, jqgrid

Is there a way to make all columns on a grid NOT sortable other than adding `sortable:false` to each column?  I know you can set global options at the grid level but didn't know if you could do it at the colModel level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no global setting in jqGrid which corresponds to the `sortable:false` from the `colModel`. Moreover jqGrid read **directly** the value of `colModel` without usage some default setting per every column element. So you have to define `sortable:false` in every column explicitly.

On the other side you can do following:

```
// we define simplified column model without repeating of the same information
var cm = [
    {name:'id', key: true},
    {name:'name'},
    // ...
];
// new we define "our standard" properties which will be the same in all columns
var myStdModel = {width: 150, sortable: false};

// we extend (or overwrite) "our standard" properties
for (var i=0; i<cm.length; i++) {
    $.extend(cm, myStdModel);
    cm.index = cm.name;
}

$("#list").jqGrid ({
    colModel: cm, // we use the column model built before
    // all other settings
});
```

In the way you can probably archive the same results which you want, but in the other way.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  We went with adding `sortable:false` to each column.

Comment: @Marcus: I suggested and could convinced Tony to include in the next release of jqGrid templates for columns in `colModel` (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/templates-for-columns-in-colmodel/ for more details). The current jqGrid sources on https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/ already include the new feature. I think, that the news will be interesting for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use colmodel template to achieve this

```
cmTemplate: {sortable:false}
```