# jqGrid: Disable sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am adding rows manually to jqGrid using `addRowData`, and the order of these rows must be maintained.

However, when paging, all rows are reordered to sort by the grid's first visible column.

I have turned off all sorting options that I can find documented.

How can I prevent all sorting and maintain the order of rows across all pages?

**Code**

Initialization code being used:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
  autowidth: false,
  cmTemplate: {sortable: false},
  colModel: config.gridColumnModel
  height: 600,
  pager: "#aggregationToolbar",
  sortable: false,
  shrinkToFit: false
  url: "fetch",
  viewrecords: false
});
```

Default settings being used (overridden by the options in the initialization code above):

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
  altClass: "altRow",
  altRows: true,
  autowidth: true,
  cmTemplate: {
    align: "center",
    title: false
  },
  datatype: "local",
  gridview: true,
  height: "auto",
  hidegrid: false,
  jsonReader: {
    page: function(obj) { return 1; },
    records: function(obj) { return obj.length; },
    repeatitems: false,
    root: "objects",
    total: function(obj) { return 1; }
  },
  loadonce: true,
  rowList: [50, 100, 250],
  rowNum: 100,
  sortable: true,
  toppager: true,
  viewrecords: true
});
```

Comment: Which value has parameter `sortname` of jqGrid? Why you need use `addRowData`? Which `datetype` you use? It's better if you included the code which you use.

Comment: "sortname" is not being used at all.  "addRowData" is used because of some necessary post-processing that is required.  The "datatype" is local.

Comment: In the code example which you posted the `datatype` is not defined so `datatype: 'xml'` will be used. Do you use any default settings? Which one? If you use `'local'` datatype you can use `data` parameter of jqGrid which work much more quickly and support of all local features like paging, sorting and filtering. Could you include small demo with the test data which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Could you include definition of `config.gridColumnModel` which you use? Could you include test data (at lest two rows)? It can be important to know how which rowid you use. Has the rows `id` property?

Comment: Could you write more about the "post-processing" which is the main reason of the usage of `addRowData` and probably event `datetype: 'local'`. I suspect you try to solve your original problem in a wrong way. Do you load the data from the server and need modify the data received from the server *before* filling in the grid? In the case there are much more effective way as usage `datatype: 'local'` and in any way the usage of `addRowData` in 99% of cases are not needed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For versions that support `cmTemplate`, you can use:

`cmTemplate: { sortable: false }`

---

**[cmTemplate](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)**: Defines a set of properties which override the default values in colModel. For example if you want to make all columns not sortable, then only one propery here can be specified instead of specifying it in all columns in colModel

Answer (score 22):

Depending on the jqGrid version you need to make `sortable: false` on each column specifically + explicitly...

For references see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989736/jqgrid-make-all-columns-not-sortable), [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/templates-for-columns-in-colmodel/) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/).